# Transformer with hysteresis in LTspice

Tags: transformer, spice, non-linear

I would like to model a transformer in LTspice with hysteresis and saturation (or just hysteresis would be nice). I have already tried the Chen model which I don't like and tried to model a regular transformer with the inductor parameters found [here](http://ltwiki.org/index.php5?title=The_Arbitrary_Inductor_model) but got an error.

Here is an example of my LTspice netlist

```
.param Is=2A a=3
.param Ind 1000mH 
K2 L4 L3 1
L4 0 N008 {2*Ind} Ipk=2 Rser=10
L3 0 N007 flux={Ind*Is}*tanh((x/{Is})**{a})**{1/a} Ipk=2 Rser=110
```

I get an error that says: mutual inductance statements aren't supported between arbitrary inductors

My question is: is there some way to combine an ideal transformer and a non-linear inductor to make an accurate model and simulate in LTspice?
Are there other ways to effectively model a transformer with hysteresis in spice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a great article [at this site](http://www.intusoft.com/articles/satcore.pdf) to model transformers. It explains

> "The work of Hsu, Middlebrook and Cuk [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQcFX.png) develops the relationship of
>   leakage inductance, showing that relatively simple measurements of
>   input inductance with shorted outputs yield the necessary model
>   information."

They developed this for IsSpice, but it could be applied anywhere.
Here is the spice code for a saturable core (just in case the link goes down)
[image]
Here is an included picture of the model
[image]
This is a graph of a modeled core:
[image]

And here is the reference for the paper the article was based on:
TRANSFORMER MODELING AND DESIGN FOR LEAKAGE CONTROL
Shi Ping Hsu, R.D. Middlebrook and Slobodan Cuk, Power conversion International,
pg. 68, Feb, 1982

Comment: Can you please explain how to calculate the parameter Lsat and Feddy .The paper have explained it but i couldn't understand it.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out this page (and, maybe even the rest of the site): [transformers](http://ltwiki.org/?title=Transformers). Even the manual should have told you about the possibility of having a Chan core in LTspice, while looking at the default examples that come with the installation of LTspice, should have given you a nice example of using it. I've pointed you in the right way, so now I'll leave it to you the pleasure of finding out, rather than coming up with a silver platter. :-)

Comment: Lt wiki is a great site, I use it on a weekly basis